# Ruby Hash#select{} with If condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to select all keyword until by cumulative `SUM < X`. This does not work because the `return true` stops the script.

```
cum_sum = 0
keywords = keywords.select{|k| 

cum_sum += k[:contribution]

if cum_sum < top
   return true
else
   return false
 end 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block return value is value of the last statement, you can just write:

```rb
cum_sum = 0
keywords = keywords.select{|k|
 cum_sum += k[:contribution]
 cum_sum < top
}
```

Also there's [Enumerable#take_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) that's more suitable for your use case

Comment: You can use `take_while` to stop as soon as cum_sum is reached
``` 
keywords = keywords.take_while{|k| 
  cum_sum += k[:contribution]
  cum_sum < top
}.to_h
```